# codeigniter input->post() is null from jquery ajax post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have several rows of data populated using database data at run time. Each row has a button. On click button i want to delete that row from database. I put a `data-id` on that button. On click the button send an ajax request to php. But i get `null` id in php. Following code i use. 

**HTML**

```
<span id="delete_btn" class="btn btn-default" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <i class="glyph-icon icon-close"> Delete</i>
</span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#feedbackTable').on('click', '#delete_btn', function (event) {

     var client_id = $(this).data('id');


    console.log(client_id); // I get the exact id
    $.ajax({
        url: url + 'client/delete',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'id' : client_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        error: function (error_data) {
           console.log(error_data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**Client.php**

```
public function delete_client() {
    if ($this->input->method(TRUE) == 'POST') {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');

        if (is_numeric($id)) {
            $id = intval($id);
            echo json_encode(array(
                "is_error" => false,
                "message" => $id
            ));
            return;
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array(
                "is_error" => true,
                "message" => $id
            ));
            return;
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "is_error" => true,
            "message" => "Invalid request"
        ));
        return;
    }
}
```

javascript console prints an user id.
but in ajax response console prints

```
Object {is_error: true, message: null}
```

what i am doing wrong? Sorry for my poor English. TIA

Comment: you used `delete` method in ajax but your method name is `delete_client`. Adjust all these things & then check my answer

Comment: I routed from `delete` to `delete_client` in `route.php` for no specific reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `is_numeric()` you may convert value by type casting. Try following

```
public function delete_client() {
    if ($this->input->method(TRUE) == 'POST') {
        $id = (int) $this->input->post('id');

        if (!empty($id)) {
            echo json_encode(array(
                "is_error" => false,
                "message" => $id
            ));
            return;
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array(
                "is_error" => true,
                "message" => $id
            ));
            return;
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "is_error" => true,
            "message" => "Invalid request"
        ));
        return;
    }
}
```

Secondly remove unnecessary params from your ajax

```
$('#feedbackTable').on('click', '#delete_btn', function (event) {

     var client_id = $(this).data('id');


    console.log(client_id); // I get the exact id
    $.ajax({
        url: url + 'client/delete',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'id' : client_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (error_data) {
           console.log(error_data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Following removed.

```
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
```

`contentType`, `processData` etc used when your form contain images etc etc. Not required here

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with `is_numeric()` but is a problem with `json` and `post` request, because `id` is `null` in php `post` method. Removing those parameter from ajax works. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  var client_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

instead of

```
  var client_id = $(this).data('id');
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried on both ways. Still same problem. I get the `client_id` in jquery correctly on the line `console.log(client_id);`. but in php `id` becomes null.

Answer (score 0):

First try sending the Ajax request without attaching to click event along with { too:  'far'} data then check for bar on the server side and reply me. 
Will like to knw why multiple element are having same is attribute.

```
<span id="delete_btn" class="btn btn-default"..
```

Instead of 
     class="delete_btn"

Comment: My mistake. multiple `id` with same name works though. I'll change that. Thanks ! 
And this change didn't solve the problem. :(

Comment: I told you send a dummy data to that url and check the response first without click event

Comment: Oh, sorry! Checked it.